# Sql Server Geometry Column causing query to take long time to run

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial-index, spatial-query

I have written a query to fetch the polygon data from Sql database.

I have following query to fetch the results.

```
SELECT ZIP,
       NAME,
       STABB,
       AREA,
       TYPE,
       orgZc.OrganizationId,
       orgZc.[ZipCode] AS ORGzip,
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(GEOM.STAsText(),'POLYGON ((',' '),'MULTIPOLYGON (((',' '),'))',''),')))','')AS WKT
FROM USZIP
INNER JOIN ORGANIZTION_ZIP_CODES orgZc ON orgZc.[ZipCode]=USZIP.zip
WHERE orgZc.OrganizationId=@ORGANIZATION_ID
```

On this table i have already added a spatial index as below

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SIndx_SpatialTable_geometry_col1 
ON USZIP(GEOM) WITH ( BOUNDING_BOX = ( -90, -180, 90, 180 ) );
```

But it took 38 sec to fetch the 2483 records. Can anyone help me to optimize this query

Comment: Indexes tends to assist when search predicates in the `WHERE` clause can benefit from using them. But your `WHERE` clause doesn't appear to reference the geometry column at all. Why did you think the index would help?

Comment: Your correct  Damien_The_Unbeliever. But i need to fetch based on zip all the geometry values

Comment: Zip column is primary column so i have already index on that. I am fetching geometry values for the zip codes belongs to a organization

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that important part of your query is the `from` and `where` clauses.  However, you can test this by removing the line:

```
   REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(GEOM.STAsText(),'POLYGON ((',' '),'MULTIPOLYGON (((',' '),'))',''),')))','')AS WKT
```

To see if that processing is taking up a lot of time.

For this part of the query:

```
FROM USZIP INNER JOIN
     ORGANIZATION_ZIP_CODES orgZc
     ON orgZc.[ZipCode] = USZIP.zip
WHERE orgZc.OrganizationId = @ORGANIZATION_ID;
```

You say that the zip code is "a primary column".  However, it has to be the *first* column in a composite index (or primary key) in order to be used for the join.  So, you really want an index on `USZIP(zip)` for the join to work.  (I'm guessing this is true based on the name of the table, but I want to be explicit.)

Second, your `where` clause is limited to one `OriganizationId`, presumably of many.  If so, you want an index on `ORGANIZATION_ZIP_CODES(OrganizationId)`.  Or, better yet, on `ORGANIZATION_ZIP_CODES(OrganizationId, ZipCode)`.

Comment: I removed the line as you said .It just took fraction of seconds.   I work with single organization at a time

Comment: @ChandraMohan . . . Bummer.  That means that the join optimizations probably won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I added a new column and updated REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(GEOM.STAsText(),'POLYGON ((',' '),'MULTIPOLYGON (((',' '),'))',''),')))','')AS WKT Now i can fetch from the newly added column directly without doing any manipulations. Now it is taking 3 sec to fetch 2483 records